# How to write a shell script to swap columns in txt file?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I was trying to solve one of my old assignment I am literally stuck in this one Can anyone help me?

There is a file called "datafile". This file has names of some friends and their

ages. But unfortunately, the names are not in the correct format. They should be

lastname, firstname

But, by mistake they are  firstname,lastname

The task of the problem is  writing a shell script called fix_datafile

to correct the problem, and sort the names alphabetically. The corrected filename

is called datafile.fix .

Please make sure the original structure of the file should be kept untouched.

The following is the sample of datafile.fix file:

#******************************personal information******************************

#******** Name *********     ***** age *****

Alexanderovich,Franklin        47

Amber,Christine            54

Applesum,Franky            33

Attaboal,Arman             18

Balad,George              38

Balad,Sam               19

Balsamic,Shery             22

Bojack,Steven             33

Chantell,Alex             60

Doyle,Jefry              45

Farland,Pamela             40

Handerman,jimmy            23

Kashman,Jenifer            25

Kasting,Ellen             33

Lorux,Allen              29

Mathis,Johny              26

Maxter,Jefry              31

Newton,Gerisha             40

Osama,Franklin             33

Osana,Gabriel             61

Oxnard,George             20

Palomar,Frank             24

Plomer,Susan              29

Poolank,John              31

Rochester,Benjami           40

Stanock,Verona             38

Tenesik,Gabriel            29

Whelsh,Elsa              21

Comment: Should it be bash script or you can use for example python?

Comment: It should be bash can you help me Please?

Comment: Can you use awk?

Comment: I dont think so .Please help me with this I am stuck since morning

Comment: What exactly are you stuck with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to read the file and swap the words but I cant make it work firstName and lastName are seperated by , and the age is space seperated I dont know how to handle that

Comment: The cut command will help you with this.

Comment: can you explain how to solve this problem please write the answer :)

Comment: Yet another assignment that mandates the use of `bash` for something you would never actually do in pure `bash` (if things like `awk` and `cut` are indeed prohibited). Please clarify exactly what you can or cannot use.

Comment: I think we can use awk and cut as @TarasKhalymon has answered

Comment: You can almost certainly use `awk`.  Is this an assignment for a course?  Not using the appropriate tool (which is awk) for the task should result in a decreased score.

Comment: I've implemented both `awk` and `sed` solutions and I think `sed` is better in this case, because it doesn't require additional efforts to preserve file structure.

Comment: I am doing previous assignment it doesnot belong to any course It is not to be evaluated I am learning for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use `awk` (I suppose you can), than this there's a script which does what you need:

```
#!/bin/bash
RESULT_FILE_NAME="datafile.new"
cat datafile.fix | head -4 > datafile.new
cat datafile.fix | tail -n +5 | awk -F"[, ]" '{if(!$2){print()}else{print($2","$1, $3)}}' >> datafile.new
```

Passing `-F"[, ]"` allows `awk` to split columns both by , and space and all that remains is just print columns in a needed format. The downsides are that we should use `if` statement to preserve empty lines and file header also should be treated separately.

Another option is using `sed`:

```
cat datafile.fix | sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z]+),([a-zA-Z]+) ([0-9]+)/\2,\1 \3/g' > datafile.new
```

The downside is that it requires regex that is not as obvious as `awk` syntax.

Comment: there will be a similar expression as `awk` , but using `sed`. It's just another test processor and it doesn't make a major difference

Comment: Just added a solution using `sed`. It works better because it preserves file structure

Comment: There is no need for cat and head when using awk as awk can do all this processing for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F[,\ ] '
         !/^$/ && !/^#/ { 
                          first=$1;
                          last=$2;
                          map[first][last]=$0 
                        } 
                    END { 
                          PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc";
                          for (i in map) { 
                                            for (j in map[i]) 
                                                            { 
                                                              print map[i][j] 
                                                            } 
                                         } 
                         }' namesfile  > datafile.fix
```

One liner:

```
awk -F[,\ ] '!/^$/ && !/^#/ { first=$1;last=$2;map[first][last]=$0 } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc";for (i in map) { for (j in map[i]) { print map[i][j] } } }' namesfile > datafile.fix
```

A solution completely in gawk.

Set the field separator to both , and space. Then ignore any lines that are empty or start with #. Mark the first and last variables based on the delimited fields and then create a two dimensional array called map indexed by first and last name and the value equal to the line. At the end, set the sort to indices string ascending and loop through the array printing the names in order as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using awk and sed.
Try if this works

```
less dataflie.fix | sed 's/ /,/g' | awk -F "," '{print $2,$1,$3}' | sed 's/ /,/' | sed 's/^,//' | sort -u  > dataflie_new.fix
```

Comment: Try to minimise piping as much as possible as this leads to inefficiency. There should be no need to pipe to sed and then sed again later on..

Answer (score 0):

Completely in bash:

```sh
re="^[[:space:]]*([^#]([[:space:]]|[[:alpha:]])+),(([[:space:]]|[[:alpha:]])*[[:alpha:]]) *([[:digit:]]+)"
while read line
do
  if [[ ${line} =~ $re ]]
  then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[3]},${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
  else 
    echo "${line}"
  fi 
done < names.txt
```

The core of this is to capture, using `bash` regex matching (`=~` operator of the `[[` command), parenthesis groupings, and the `BASH_REMATCH` array, the name before the comma (`([^#]([[:space:]]|[[:alpha:]])+)`), the name after the comma (`(([[:space:]]|[[:alpha:]])*[[:alpha:]])`), and the age ( `*([[:digit:]]+)`). The first-name regex is constructed so as to exclude comments, and the last-name regex is constructed as to handle multiple spaces before the age without including them in the name. Preconditions: Commented lines with or without leading spaces (`^[[:space:]]*([^#]`), or lines without a comma, are passed through unchanged. Either first names or last names may have internal spaces. Once the last name and first name are isolated, it is easy to print them in reverse order followed by the age (`echo ${BASH_REMATCH[3]},${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[5]}`). Note that the letter/space groupings are counted as matches which is why we skip 2 and 4.